# Having trouble with functions and transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to apologize in advance if what I'm writing might be wrong. I'm currently studying linear algebra and I've reached the chapter on transformations. We've started the chapter with a definition of a function which basically says we're associating one element from set A (our domain) to another element from set B (our codomain). For instance, given something like:

$$f(x) = x^2$$

We can say that:
$f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $f: x\mapsto x^2$

So we are associating every $x$ from our domain with one element from our range (a subset of our domain) whose value is $x^2$.

If I extended this to 3-space and said:

$$g(x,y) = x+y$$

I assume we can say (please correct me if I'm wrong): $g: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g: x,y \mapsto x+y$

The way I think (or at least know) of functions is that we're given an input and get one thing out of it. So in our first example if we're given an $x$ we get out a $y$. In the second example, if we're given an ordered pair $(x,y)$ we get out our $z$. My confusion happened while watching a video when this example was given:

Define a function $h$ such that: $$h: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$$
$$h(x_1, x_2) = (x_1+x_2, x_2-x_1, x_2x_1)$$

What is exactly is going on here? I know we've associated an ordered pair $(x_1,x_2)$ with an ordered triplet $(x_1+x_2, x_2-x_1, x_2x_1)$ but how is this even possible? Usually when I see something like $f(x)$ or $f(x,y)$ my mind says I'm only going to get one point out of it. Going back to our original examples, $f(2) = 4$ and $g(1,1) = 2$. How are we getting a 3-tuple in the $h(x)$ case? How does $h(x_1, x_2) = (x_1+x_2, x_2-x_1, x_2x_1)$ even look like if I wanted to write it explicitly as a function? Is this function in something like a 5-d coordinate system?

Comment: The codomain of a function need not be $\mathbb{R}$ always. Here, for $h$, the codomain is $\mathbb{R}^3$. $h(x_1,x_2)=(x_1+x_2, x_2-x_1, x_2x_1)$ is the explicit formula of $h$.

Comment: Please forgive my confusion, it's just that usually when I see something like $f(x) = x$ and $f(1) = 1$, that would imply I plot the point (1,1) on the graph. I assume what the $h(x)$ above is saying is if I chose h(1,2), I would plot (3,1,2) on my 3d-coordinate system, right? @Extremal

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.